# How to ensure a user doesn't miss a webpage crucial for constructive usage of another webpage?

Tags: html, payments, accessibility, architecture, contact-page

I have a problem of the need to ensure that a user doesn't miss a webpage crucial for *what I assume as a constructive usage* of another web page.

### Personal example of this problem

My website contains a `pricelist` webpage and a `contact` webpage containing a simple contact form, which contains the following mandatory fields:

- Name
- Email
- Type of service in which the inquirer is interested (selected from a selection list of up to five options)

### Possible solutions for this problem

#### 1. Noting that prices are available in pricelist before each form submission

This is the simplest solution I know of and took it so far:

Each selection option in the select list of my contact form contains a parenthesis note according to which price is available in price list:

```
VARIABLE message = "price is available in price list"
```

<sub>Per variable call in each job description line:</sub>

> - Job 1 (price is available in price list)
> - Job 2 (price is available in price list)
> - Job 3 (price is available in price list)
> - Job 4 (price is available in price list)
> - Job 5 (price is available in price list)

The main problem with this approach is that it *might* feel absurd to a customer although I personally assume a customer who really needs some proposed job wouldn't care from it much and would inquire anyway but I have no objective evidence for this assumption

---

#### 2. Uniting two webpages

Similar to what I understood from Stephen Ostermiller's comments, this is problematic in this case, because, even if the contact form is under the pricelist:

- A potential customer might want to know prices without contacting → not knowing prices are in the contact webpage which may cause stress when visiting that web page.
- If a potential customer clicked on a contact and then percepted a pricelist it might confuse that potential customer
- A link such as "prices and contact is quite long and possible very not intuitive

### Notes

- My pricelist page contains notes about international payment options and some other notes which makes the page a bit longer than just a table of prices and is also splitted to three chapters, each one dealing with another type of service; henceforth, I consider it a crucial webpage and would like any potential customer to use it
- Setphen Ostermiller commented:

> Somebody could explain how to pull information from a centralized
>   database into two different pages or say how to set up AJAX calls to
>   get the information from one page to the other.

If this is still relevant after the massive edit of this question, I would welcome an answer further explaining what is proposed to be done --- what is proposed to be presented in two different ways for a potential customer, via two different Ajax calls, as a solution to the problem.

### My question

How to ensure a user doesn't miss a webpage crucial for constructive usage of another webpage?

Comment: What is somebody wants to see prices but doesn't want to contact you?  Do they have to look at your contact page to find out prices?  How would they know to do that?   If they got there by clicking on "price list", wouldn't the contact form confuse them?  Would they know to look past it?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller sorry if I am nuddgy about this but `A potential customer might want to know prices without contacting → not knowing prices are in the "contact us" webpage which may cause stress when visiting that web page.` AND `If a potential customer clicked on a "contact us" and then percepted a pricelist it might confuse that potential customer` aren't a good summary of your above comment?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good summary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how the OP resolved the issue presented....

I think they should have developed 5 separate pages: one for each job level. Each page would have contained information about the specified job level itself, estimated price range, and a short form to request additional information.

My solution would have combined the information, price, and contact on each page, all with a similar format. This would allow the site visitor to focus specifically on what they were looking for without a lot of hunting. And it would allow the site owner to treat each job level as a separate "landing page" for SEO purposes.